# Facebook SDK Graph API posting message on the wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My Facebook app's Status and Review feedback suggests not to pre-fill text while posting on wall. But I can found the use of `message` param in the Facebook Graph API documentation [Graph API Publishing section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed).

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is a test message");
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/feed",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I have verified it and it works fine. Is it allowed as per updated Facebook policies ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message must be 100% user generated, so if you present an (EMPTY!) input field where the user can enter the message before you do the API call, it´s fine. Prefilling means that you prefill the message or the input field, which is not allowed.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill